# GetProperty - Reading a property via reflection + SSIS Custom Component

Tags: c#, ssis, custom-component

Am in process of building my custom component.  Am trying to read values of PipleBuffer by 
GetProperty("propertyname").GetValue() as below:

```
    public override void ProcessInput(int inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
    {
        while (buffer.NextRow())
        {
            string nk = buffer[1].ToString();
            string nk1 = buffer.GetType().GetProperty("NK").GetValue(buffer, null).ToString();
```

at line buffer[1].ToString() work fine,
but at next line it fails throwing :

NullReferenceException : object reference not set to an instance of an object

Any clues please.

Cannot create object instance of PipleBuffer as is under protection level.

Comment: Whate exactly are you trying to accomplish with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `buffer.GetType().GetProperty("NK")` is null, or `buffer.GetType().GetProperty("NK").GetValue(buffer, null)` is null.

Change your code as follows and find out:

```
PropertyInfo prop = buffer.GetType().GetProperty("NK");
if (prop == null)
{
    throw new Exception("prop is null!");
}

object value = prop.GetValue(buffer, null);
if (value == null)
{
    throw new Exception("value is null!");
}

string nk1 = value.ToString();
```

Note this is for diagnostic purposes only. I don't propose you keep this in your code!